# SQL || Calculate time spend in each city (Field)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck in the situation where I need to calculate the time spend in particular city.
Here i have three column:

1. Time -- Current time to move to particular city
2. Add_City -- Current City
3. Remove_City -- Previous City moved from

[image: Time Add_City Remove_City 2021-03-21 12:40:00 Null Null 2021-03-21 12:45:00 A B 2021-03-21 14:07:00 Null Null 2021-03-21 15:32:00 B A 2021-03-21 19:51:00 Null Null 2021-03-21 20:10:00 A B]

So the whole scenario is like , let us take an example:

[image: 2021-03-21 12:40:00 Null Null 2021-03-21 12:45:00 A B]

In first row, as nothing is mentioned in add and remove city , it means person hasnt moved from one to another.
Now going on second row as it suggests it moved from B to A, hence current time is for A while it stayed in B from 2021-03-21 12:40:00 to 2021-03-21 12:45:00.

I have to calculate the total time taken in each city.

Comment: Are there more fields in this table you can provide? With just these three fields, there's no way of knowing which city the '2021-03-21 12:40:00' record is referring to.

Comment: Following your explanation, looking just at the first two rows: on 2021-03-21 at 12:40 nothing happened, and at 12:45 the person ("it"?) moved from B to A. So this means for those five minutes, from 12:40 to 12:45, the person was in B. Fine, but where was the person **before** 12:40? Or do you not care about that, and you must only consider those five minutes? (Plus, of course, what can be found by looking at additional rows from the input data.) Then: with this data model, after the person moves from B to A, how do you *guarantee* that the next move is "from" A, and not "from" E?

Comment: Also: Please provide the sample data as plain text, which can be copied and pasted. No one can test on images (and a lot of us volunteers on this forum like to test our solutions, although not everyone does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's create the sample data. This is how you should provide it to us:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi';

create table sample_data (time, add_city, remove_city) as
    select to_date('21-03-2021 12:40'), null, null from dual union all
    select to_date('21-03-2021 12:45'), 'A' , 'B'  from dual union all
    select to_date('21-03-2021 14:07'), null, null from dual union all
    select to_date('21-03-2021 15:32'), 'B' , 'A'  from dual union all
    select to_date('21-03-2021 19:51'), null, null from dual union all
    select to_date('21-03-2021 20:10'), 'A' , 'B'  from dual
;
```

Then, if I understand the problem correctly, here is one way to solve it. I assume you want the "time spent in each city" shown as an `interval day to second`; if you just want it in "days" (as a decimal number), just use `sum(duration)` in the outer query.

```
with
  prep (duration, city) as (
    select lead(time) over (order by time) - time,
           nvl(last_value (add_city    ignore nulls) over (order by time),
               first_value(remove_city ignore nulls) over (order by time
                           rows  between current row and unbounded following))
    from   sample_data
  )
select city, numtodsinterval(sum(duration), 'day') as time_in_city
from   prep
group  by city
order  by city
;

CITY TIME_IN_CITY       
---- -------------------
A    +00 02:47:00.000000
B    +00 04:43:00.000000
```